# SharePoint page custom list to page

Tags: list, wiki-pages

I have created SharePoint site using Visual Studio. I have also created list and I have added some custom fields. However, I can see list in quick launch. Is there anyway to show list on page? How I can add list to page, so I don't have to click it in quick launch? So, list is part on text page layout? Any guide how to do this? Or how I add it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provision a view to a page by using a module

The example below will provision a list view web part on the default.aspx page into RightWebPartZone using the list view with BaseViewID=3 for list with url Lists/MyList

```
<Module Name="MyPages" Url="$Resources:cmscore,List_Pages_UrlName;" Path="pages">
  <File Url="default.aspx" Type="GhostableInLibrary" Level="Published">
     <View
           List="Lists/MyList"
            BaseViewID="3"
            Name="MyList"
            WebPartZoneID="RightWebPartZone"
            WebPartOrder="0" />
      ...
    </File>
</Module>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can add it as a **listview webpart**.

Following are the steps:

- Edit the page
- Click on Add webpart.
- Click on lists.
- Select the list to be added to the page.

  [Reference](http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/windows-sharepoint-services-help/displaying-sharepoint-lists-in-web-parts-HA001126557.aspx)